# Pandas catch error using when using 'apply'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am geocoding a dataset using the column 'Address'. I would like to either add the string 'N/A' to the row 'lat' when an attribute exception is thrown or simply remove that row if the error is thrown.

Here is what I have tried to make the row with the exception say 'N/A':

```
try:
    addresses['lat'] = addresses['Address'].apply(addLat)
    addresses['long'] = addresses['Address'].apply(addLong)
except AttributeError:
  addresses['lat'] = 'N/A' # this makes every column say N/A
```

I have also tried:

```
try:
    addresses['lat'] = addresses['Address'].apply(addLat)
    addresses['long'] = addresses['Address'].apply(addLong)
except AttributeError:
  addresses['lat'] = 'N/A' # this makes every column say N/A
  pass # this makes the lat column not exists
```

but the result of this is having no lat/long columns at all.

My question is, how can I access the specific index of the exception and either ignore or insert 'N/A' during an exception?

I have confirmed that the geocode function works on multiple individual rows of the dataset & am certain that my geocoding function is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You want to include your exception handling inside of the apply method.  This uses a wrapper function `exception_handler` to handle exceptions for the inner function:

```
def exception_handler(func, x):
    try:
        return func(x)
    except AttributeError:
        return 'N/A'
    
addresses['lat'] = addresses['Address'].apply(lambda x: exception_handler(addLat, x))
addresses['long'] = addresses['Address'].apply(lambda x: exception_handler(addLong, x))
```

Alternatively, you could add the try except block to your `addLat` and `addLong` functions.